# Redirect do JSF web no mobile não esta funcionando!

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, wildfly

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto estudantil com JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.0 e wildfly 8, e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Minha Aplicação funciona normalmente quando eu acesso de um dispositivo desktop, porem quando eu tento acessar de um dispositivo Mobile, vou na tela de login e quando faço o procedimento de "logar", sou redirecionado para mesma pagina de login não conseguindo acessar a aplicação.

O Log não apresenta erros, usei log4j para acompanhar os procedimentos e tudo acontece como deveria acontecer, porem na hora de efetuar o redirect a aplicação não se comporta como deve.

Estou fazendo o `redirect`da seguinte forma:

`return "/autenticate/escolhaperfil.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";`

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: O botão de login está usando `action` ou `actionListener`?

Comment: Está usando action!